# If I use Stack Exchange Android app, will my visit be counted?

Tags: support, badges, android-app, consecutive-days

If I use Stack Exchange Android app, will my visit be counted for the Enthusiast & Fanatic badges?

Comment: I'm 100% sure it should be counted. It would make no sense to allow you to visit a site using your account without taking a note of your contribution using that medium.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Should I have to go into individual site or just opening the app is enough. Last week I used the app, but my visit is not counted for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky How you are suggesting to test without loosing the continuous day visit??

Comment: Why not? is so simple. On a given day visit from your android app that very specific site where you want to maintain your visits. Then later in the day visit using a computer and notice "last seen", you will get your answer if your previous visit counted

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky It is showing 6 mins ago but i visted the site from mobile app just now

Comment: Then the answer to your question will probably be `no` and only a mod or any other senior member can tell

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky That doesn't make it off-topic, this is a question about the SE Android App and is entirely on-topic here.

Comment: Close Vote retracted

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, each visit to a site using the Android App is counted, and you can earn the Enthusiast & Fanatic badges using the App only! And it's counted in *Last Seen* in your profile as well.

But, you need to **visit each single** site separately. It's **NOT** enough to open the App to count your visit in all accounts you have!

So, all you need to do to earn those badges, is to open each site you want for 30 & 100 consecutive days. *(Days are counted in UTC)*.

PS: FYI and to assure you, I've earned the Enthusiast badge using the App, and in my way to earn the Fanatic one. :)

Comment: I assume this applies to the iOS app, too.