# Does using the Stack Exchange app count for the visit badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, android-app, ios-app

Do uses of the Stack Exchange mobile application count toward the [Enthusiast](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast) and [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic) badges?

I recognize that this question [has been asked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252475/if-i-use-stack-exchange-android-app-will-my-visit-be-counted), but I'm re-asking it for two reasons:

- The original was never answered.
- There is now an [iOS Stack Exchange app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8), so whether it counts is even more important.

Comment: There's an answer here somewhere. "Yes" is the answer, but more than just viewing your feed.

Comment: So, for example, do you need to *view* a question or answer to make it count? Just for information.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/254778) post, yes visiting the site from the Android and iOS app **do** count toward the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.

> We're now counting access to a site via the app for both "last seen" and the "daily site access" for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.
>
> As is true with the sites, we don't actually count all access; only those actions we consider "real". For the mobile app, this basically means accessing the feed doesn't count; we'll probably tweak what we consider "real" over time.

Comment: It would be nice to have the criteria for a successful logon. I just lost my count after 50ish days because I didn't know a simple *feed viewing* on the app wouldn't count.