# Why does mobile access not count for fanatic badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I just want to know why Stack Overflow does not count mobile access. I don't have my personal laptop and I have been using Stack Overflow continuously for the last two years, as you can see on my profile: **visited 533 days, 2 consecutive**.

Last week I noticed that I was not getting the fanatic badge because I don't access Stack Overflow on the weekend (two Days). I decided to access Stack Overflow on mobile and then I accessed from mobile in last two days but today still counter reset to 2, while I was expecting 8.

Can someone let me know the reason for this?

Comment: Mobile does count. Even [using the app counts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256086/does-using-the-stack-exchange-app-count-for-the-visit-badges). Did you actually do anything though? Things like visiting your profile or just the homepage do not count as site access. The calendar on your profile says you missed Friday.

Comment: _"I am sorry if it is an off topic"_ Nope, not at all. Issues such as this are exactly what meta was created for.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256086/does-using-the-stack-exchange-app-count-for-the-visit-badges?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It may help to understand that a "StackOverflow" day and your day likely _do not align_. AFAIK it's based off of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So right now for me it's 12:45am - but for SO it's 6:45am... You can check the UTC time by clicking the **Achievements** button at the top of any SO page, which it will say: **ACHIEVEMENTS** UTC TIME 06:46
[privileges](/help/privileges) • [badges](/help/badges)

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Yes may be that's why. But in weekend I have access lot of time. May be more than 5 times in single day

Comment: You need to do more than just look. What exactly counts as access is not public.

Comment: I nearly always use the mobile browser, and just a visit to the homepage is enough to count (no votes, no nothing), and I'm at 99/100 days for the fanatic badge. It does work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you agree with DavyM ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer: I'm just reporting on what I know. See [Consecutive days problem #97?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66482), logging in does not count. Also see [What are the exact requirements for the woot/enthusiast badge?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/24884).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your report

Comment: I just got the Fanatic Badge on the main site, with all I did was click through to meta from the main site on mobile, and that was enough to trigger day 100. Whatever the algorithm is to determine a 'visit', it seems pretty fair and it definitely counts over mobile

Comment: (I'm still in the 80s for visits on Meta, so the badge is only on my main profile)